# SQL Query for : rows linked by one joint table link to another joint table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL. In my database I have the following tables:

1. A  `student` table. The primary key of this table is `sid` .
2. A `high_school` table. Primary key is `hid` .
3. A `university` table. Primary key is `uid` .

Then:

- There is a **joint table** for `student` & `high_school`, the table is named `joint_table_A` it has two columns : `sid` and `hid` which link to the rows in `student` & `high_school` respectively.
- There is another **joint table** for `student` & `university` , named `joint_table_B` , it also has two columns : `sid` and `uid` which link to the rows in `student` & `university` respectively.

My problem & question:

I want to have those `students` linked by `sid` in `joint_table_A`  where `hid = 3` being also link to `joint_table_B`'s `sid` and put the value of `uid` to be `1` . What is the SQL query for this operation ?

**===== UPDATE ======**

Currently I get 3 answers below, one using `JOIN`, one using `LEFT JOIN` & last one using `INNER JOIN` . I get confused by those `JOINs` (I am still learning SQL). If you could add some explanations which would be more helpful for me to understand your answers so that I know the differences among your answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM students s
INNER JOIN joint_table_A a ON s.sid = a.sid
INNER JOIN joint_table_B b ON s.sid = b.sid
WHERE a.hid = 3
  AND b.uid = 1
```

To try and explain the difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` for this query:

Imagine you have 1000 records in `students` but there is only 50 records in `joint_table_A`, giving the hid's of 50 students highschools, and another 50 in `joint_table_B`.

When you `LEFT JOIN`, all rows in the left table (`students`) are kept even if they can't be joined to a record in the right table. When you `INNER JOIN` only rows that can be joined are kept - where the `sid` exists in both left and right tables.

**Using LEFT JOIN**

1. 1000 `student` join to 50 `joint_table_A` records - after the join 950 records have `hid = NULL`.
2. 1000 records from the previous join are joined to `joint_table_B` - 950 of these have `uid = NULL`.
3. Now all 1000 records are checked for `WHERE a.hid = 3 AND b.uid = 1`

**Using INNER JOIN**

1. 1000 `student` join to 50 `joint_table_A` records - after the join only the 50 records that could join remain.
2. 50 records from the previous join are joined to `joint_table_B` - 20 of these can be joined (not all the same students who had their high school recorded also had university recorded).
3. Now 20 records are checked for `WHERE a.hid = 3 AND b.uid = 1`

You can see why `INNER JOIN` is the one to use in this situation.

Comment: In this situation an INNER JOIN is what you want - (JOIN is the same apparently, I always explicitly declare what type of JOIN I am using though). In a LEFT JOIN you keep all the records from the students table in the result set even if they do not match any records from one of the joints tables, since we are filtering based on fields from the joint tables, it doesn't make sense to filter results that don't have any value in that joint table, so you may as well get rid of them during the join - if that makes any sense. All 3 answers will give you the same result set though.

Comment: +1 for previous comment. Should be JOIN or INNER JOIN not LEFT JOIN in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student.*
FROM   student
  JOIN joint_table_A USING (sid)
  JOIN joint_table_B USING (sid)
WHERE  joint_table_A.hid = 3
   AND joint_table_B.uid = 1
```

Comment: @Mellon: `JOIN` is simply shorthand for `INNER JOIN`.  The difference with `LEFT JOIN` is best explained by [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM student s
    LEFT JOIN joint_table_A a ON a.sid=s.sid
    LEFT JOIN high_school h ON h.hid=a.sid
    LEFT JOIN joint_table_B b ON b.sid=s.sid
    LEFT JOIN university u ON u.uid=b.uid
WHERE h.hid = 3 AND u.uid=1
```

Comment: @Mellon see eggyal comment

Comment: You should use JOIN or INNER JOIN not LEFT JOIN as in my answer above. My mistake.